# Connect Excel to a Power BI data model

Tags: excel, powerbi

Is there any way to connect Excel to Power BI Desktop and importing the Data Model to Power Pivot?

With Power BI Publisher for Excel it is possible to connect Excel to Power BI Service and get a live connection, but the data is contained within a Pivot Table. I need to maintain a specific spreadsheet-like layout and it is complicated to create formulas linking to a Pivot Table.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Have you tried the Analyze in Excel option? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-analyze-in-excel

Comment: @AlexisOlson sure did. I get the same functionality as Power BI Publisher for Excel. That is, a Pivot Table.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't.

The way to achieve your objective is to **import your "raw" Excel data** from which you created your pivot table in Excel, and then **"re-create"** artificially your pivot table in power bi desktop thanks to the query editor and the data model manipulation capabilities.